# setup a Mysql query to display a numeric column in particular order?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a user input box, querying a column of numbers in my SQL database, which, for example are:

```
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
```

The user will have to type in a number, and then populate a particular order of the list of numbers to respond to the input from the user.
So if the user input was 4.0, then i want the database query to display

```
4.0,3.0,5.0,2.0,6.0,7.0,8.0.
```

To break the results down, I want the result pattern to display the database results with the closest number to the input(4.0),then the next result, if available, to be lower by 1 degree(3.0), then higher by 1 degree(5.0),then lower by two degrees (2.0), and higher by two degrees(6.0). The 7.0 and 8.0 numbers are displayed numerically because there is no lows to match them.

How can I setup a query for this pattern of results?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I actually did do research to find an answer to my question, but I did not have anything which was truly resembling the answer I needed...so you shouldn't assume just because I didn't state it in my question...also the link Marc B stated is a duplication of is not the same as this.  I needed something mathematical like what the answer to the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        ABS(value - 4.0), SIGN(value - 4.0)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acca2/3)

Comment: Just for knowledge. Will This be able to achieve `then the next result, if available,to be lower by 1 degree(3.0), then higher by 1 degree(5.0),then lower by two degrees (2.0), and higher by two degrees(6.0). `?

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ: why don't you try it?

Comment: Yeah it does!! Just tried, Awesome! Learned something new

Comment: @user1839373: sof.com? Did you save much on foods?